# Como conectar ao banco Firebird em Python?

Tags: python, linux, firebird

Estou fazendo uma aplicação me *Python* que deve se conectar a um banco *Firebird*.
A aplicação está rodando em um **Linux** e o banco em um **Windows**. O meu arquivo de teste funcionou corretamente no servidor **Windows**, mas no cliente, no caso **Linux**, fica travado na classe conexão.

```
con = fdb.connect(host="192.168.43.252",database="C:/DB/BANCO.FDB", user="kenta", password="1234", port=3050)

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from produto")
lista = cur.fetchall()

print(lista)

cur.close()
con.close()
```

O que devo fazer para corrigir esse problema?

**[Atualização]**: Depois de muito tempo ele retorna a mensagem de erro:

```
 SQLCODE: -902 
 - Unable to complete network request to host "192.168.43.252".
 - Failed to estabilish a connection.
```

Erro SQL:

```
 -902, 335544721
```

**[Atualização]**: Eu já instalei o **libfbclient2**, mas não encontro os arquivos:

- **/usr/lib/libfbclient.so.2**: Firebird 3.0
- **/usr/lib/libfbclient.so**: firebird 2.5

Comment: Voce consegue dar um ping a partir do cliente para o servidor? Vc consegue conectar o banco com algum outro cliente (por exemplo o [dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/download/)) que não seja o python?

Comment: O ping funciona sim. A respeito de outro cliente eu não testei.

Comment: Descobri o erro, no firewall do meu windows não estava liberado a porta de comunicação 3050. Desabilitei todo o firewall para teste e comunicou.

Answer (score 1):

O problema de comunicação estava no **Firewall** do **Windows**, a porta `3050` não estava liberada. - [kenta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/134812/kenta)